# Printing the average of combined student marks using C

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I've made this program below to calculate the average mark of a student.
Everything works well until I use -1, it is supposed to stop the program as is display the average of all students that have been entered, say Goodbye! and then terminate.

I think my calculations might be wrong though because it is printing the wrong result for the average marks of the students.
Thanks in Advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
float final_mark(int a_mark1, int a_mark2, int lab_mark, int quiz_mark, int exam_mark);
int i, a_mark1, a_mark2, lab_mark, quiz_mark, exam_mark;
float average_mark = 0.0;
do
{
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter assignment 1 mark (-1 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &a_mark1);

        if(a_mark1 == -1)
        {
            average_mark += final_mark(a_mark1, a_mark2, lab_mark, quiz_mark, exam_mark);
            if ((average_mark > 1 ) && (average_mark < 100 ))
            {
                printf("The average student mark is %.2f%% \n", average_mark);
            }
            printf("Goodbye! \n");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Enter assignment 2 mark: ");
        scanf("%d", &a_mark2);

        printf("Enter laboratory mark: ");
        scanf("%d", &lab_mark);

        printf("Enter quiz mark: ");
        scanf("%d", &quiz_mark);

        printf("Enter exam mark: ");
        scanf("%d", &exam_mark);

        printf("Student %d final mark: %.2f \n", i + 1, final_mark(a_mark1, a_mark2, lab_mark, quiz_mark, exam_mark));
    }
}
while(a_mark1 != -1);
return 0;
}
float final_mark(int a_mark1, int a_mark2, int lab_mark, int quiz_mark, int     exam_mark)
{
float final_mark = a_mark1 * 0.1 + a_mark2 * 0.15 + lab_mark * 0.15 +     quiz_mark * 0.1 + exam_mark * 0.5;
return final_mark;
}
```

Comment: `If no students have been entered and you hit -1 at the start of the program it's supposed to just say goodbye`..well, your program does not do so,

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't Sourav, it's why I'm posting here to see if anyone can point me in the right direction to getting it working

Comment: Two lines before `printf("Goodbye! \n")`, you call `final_mark`, passing in uninitialized variables. I'm not surprised you see "some crazy number."

Comment: okay so i've updated the code and it only prints out the average is a value has been entered but now my problem is that it is printing the wrong average when exiting the program. I think my equation might be wrong somewhere but I don't know where.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rethink your logic a little bit. Why not use a `while` loop to control the flow. Then you can bail out of the program immediately if user inputs -1 right away. You should use an array to store the averages for each student, then you can loop through and find the class average as well.

-Your `float final_mark` function seems a little sketchy without any parenthesis.

-You should put your function prototype outside of `main` as well. See below changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STUDENTS 10 //define what the max number of students is

float final_mark(int mark1, int mark2, int lab, int quiz, int exam);

int main()
{
   int i = 0, mark1 = 0, mark2 = 0,
       lab = 0, quiz = 0, exam = 0;
   int num_students;
   float students_avg[MAX_STUDENTS] = {0}; //array to hold averages for students
   float average = 0;

   while (i < MAX_STUDENTS) {

      printf("Enter assignment 1 mark (enter -1 to quit):\n");
      scanf("%d", &mark1);

      if (mark1 == -1)
         break; //no more students, break out of while loop

      printf("Enter assignment 2 mark: ");
      scanf("%d", &mark2);

      printf("Enter laboratory mark: ");
      scanf("%d", &lab);

      printf("Enter quiz mark: ");
      scanf("%d", &quiz);

      printf("Enter exam mark: ");
      scanf("%d", &exam);

      average = final_mark(mark1, mark2, lab, quiz, exam);

      students_avg[i] = average; //add this average to array

      printf("Student # %d average was %.2f\n", i, students_avg[i]);//debug info

      i++;
   }
   num_students = i; //how many students grades did we read?

   average = 0; //reset to 0 so we can use below

   for (i = 0; i < num_students; i++)
      average += students_avg[i];

   if (num_students > 0)
      printf("Class average is %.2f\n", average/num_students);
   else
      printf("Goodbye!\n");

   return 0;
}

float final_mark(int mark1, int mark2, int lab, int quiz, int exam)
{
   //we can just return the calculation
   return ((mark1 * 0.1) + (mark2 * 0.15) + (lab * 0.15) + (quiz * 0.1) + (exam * 0.5));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tormund, exactly what I wanted. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @r92l30 glad I could help! Feel free to accept this as the answer if it solved your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just erase two lines above printf("GOODBYE! \n"); you will get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you have to initialized mark s variables to 0. and a_mark1 to 0 too if the user enter -1